# How to get and decrypt the authenticatin cookie in a Web API MessageHandler

Tags: asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I want to write a MessageHandler which extracts the authentication cookie from a HttpRequestMessage and decrypts it in odrer to get the username of the authenticated user. I could manage to get hold of the cookie but then I'm got stuck. I know there exists the FormsAuthentication.Decrypt() method but I don't know to use it here.

```
public class FormsAuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var formsCookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        var authCookie = request.Headers.GetCookies(formsCookieName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            string username = ???

            // further processing
        }

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
public class FormsAuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var authCookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

        var authCookies = request.Headers.GetCookies(authCookieName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (authCookies != null && authCookies[authCookieName] != null)
        {
            var authCookieValue = authCookies[authCookieName].Value;
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookieValue);
            if (ticket != null)
            {
                var username = ticket.Name;

                // further processing
            }                    
        }

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```